# Dashboard Shiny: brushing no table update

Tags: shiny, flexdashboard, brush

I'm trying to modify my flexdashboard and be able to brush some points and get row/info about the brushed points in a separated table. After searching in forums, websites, ... I manage to get a first draft shown below. I can brush, I can see the table but the table update show no information.

Any tips or ideas why the table is not updating ? Thank you

Looking at the guidance, it is recommended to share shiny code using gist. First time, hope it will work. Here is the link:

https://gist.github.com/MichaelBrion/9c6a2d66d5e53d8d345d68741823a1d9

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example of the application? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I hope the gist in my initial post will be useful !